# Page View Controller Slide view controller over current view controller

Tags: uipageviewcontroller

Currently, I am using a page view controller to present multiple view controllers. However, the view controllers slide to the next controller; I have tried to change the main view controller to "Defines current context" and have set the other view controllers to "Present over current context" and yet the controllers still slide into the next. How can I get the view controllers on the right and the left to slide on top of the current Messages view controller?

[image: Display of the sliding without coming over current screen]